# How can I create a Visual C++ project out of a C++ project that has buildfile

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, makefile

I am trying to use a part of code from a C++ project. The component I need is in it's own folder so I wont need to go and find all the dependencies. The project doesn't contain a visual studio project or solution and contains it's own makefiles to be used with it's own build environment config/tool. you can choose to compile with the vc++ compiler, so I know the compiler will work fine.

So I am trying to figure out how I can create a visual studio solution/project with these files, so I can open up the project in Visual Studio and build it, work on it etc. If there is no tools, is it possible to just create a new solution and manually add the files like I can with .net projects?

I am sure it is pretty common for people to port the c++ project into a visual studio c++ project. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the General + Makefile Project template to add the project.

Comment: @HansPassant Does that work with any Makefile? If I have crazy hand-written Makefiles for example...

Comment: Of course, everybody always has crazy makefiles.  It will be obvious when you actually try it.

Comment: To create a new project from the existing files, you can try the wizard *File/New/Project from existing code* - it's normally quite easy to convert makefile projects.